# Are there any method to find URL to my admin login page?

Tags: security, url

Let's say I'm the owner of the website `http://www.example.com` and my admin login page is `http://www.example.com/admin12345`. Here `admin12345` passed in the URL as a parameter. The php code on the server decides whether to display the admin login page (if the proper parameter in the URL is `admin12345`) or not.

I don't want that page to be viewed for everyone. Only for the person that knows the path to this page. I want to make it pretty hard to guess that URL to the admin login page.

What are my steps to hide my admin login page from users?

Should I hide that page from Google search engine in `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` or any other way to reduce the number of visitors to the admin login page?

Is it true: "to guess the URL to the admin login page, `admin12345` in the URL is kind of a password. So the harder(the longer) the text `admin12345`, the harder (the longer it takes) to find the URL to the admin login page".

Is it valid for both Windows, Linux hosting?

So, I hope the answer for the question is "the only method is a brute force method".

P.S. In this example, `http://www.example.com/admin12345` is the admin login page, not an admin area yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Hiding' your admin page **is not secure**. There are a number of places it could be found including sitemaps, robots, analytics and search results.

You'll need to implement some kind of security on the page assuming that the world can (and will find it).

However there's no harm in changing the page's name to make it less obvious to a search engine/user but you must not rely on this obscurity for your security.

You can reduce the number of hits a page gets by:

- Not listing it in SiteMaps or Robots.txt
- Not linking to it from other pages in your site
- Not listing it with Google Analytics (or any other search engine monitoring tool)

Comment: Could you please explain how Google could find admin12345? I won't put any info into the sitemap file about the URL to the admin login page. Thank you.

Comment: Do you use chrome? Can you guarantee that no one who ever visits the admin page won't bookmark it in a browser in a cybercafe? What about browser histories? Your hosting provider will know the page's location! Is a perfectly secure mechanism? No - is it good enough based on the admin functionality you're exposing? That's your decision - personally I think a simple username/password combo is worth that little extra bit of time and effort

Comment: I wrote in the P.S. "not an admin area yet", the admin have to log into the admin account by providing login and password. I've just asked about how to hide the ADMIN LOGIN page from visitors, not the admin area.

Comment: If it's just the login then you're fairly safe - your site's security is not dependent on it - if someone visits it then you really don't care! :)

Comment: :-) You are right. However the number of visitors of the admin login page depends on if it is http://www.example.com/admin or http://www.example.com/admin12345 , right?

Once they find it, it could appear @ google, twitter etc. That's what I'd like to prevent (at least to reduce chances). :)

Answer (score 1):

Hiding a URL is classed as [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

URLs are not secure in themselves because:

- They are logged in browser history.
- They can be logged by proxy servers.
- Servers and other appliances often log them by default.
- They can be leaked via the [referer HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer).

Although not secure in itself, it won't hurt to give this page random name but don't rely on it for security. You should include a `meta` tag like you mentioned, which is better than using a `robots.txt` file as this file could simply be read to find out where your "secret" URL paths are. In addition to `NOINDEX` it would be wise to also include `NOFOLLOW`.

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

If you are renaming your admin area, you would probably be best to avoid the words "admin" or "login" within the path as tools such as automated scanners and [google dorks](http://www.googlebig.com/list_of_query_and_dork_of_google/) are more likely to find them. Again I must stress that these should just be additional measures made to your page which should be secure in itself assuming that the URL is known and hiding the admin page should not be used as an excuse for not securing the admin tool adequately.

Check out the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10) for the most common exploits found in 2013 with tips for how to secure your app against them.